# Дождаться завершения нескольких асинхронных запросов при помощи jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, асинхронность

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу: есть некоторое случайное количество запросов (содержатся в списке `ids`), которые надо сделать к серверу и дождаться завершения каждого из них.
Запросы формируются при помощи jQuery (*jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2*) следующим образом:

```
function request(id) {
    return $.getJSON(`my_API_URL&id=${id}&format=json`)
        .then((json) => {
            // что-то сделать с json, если нужно
            // ...
            return json;
    });
}

var requests = [];
for (var id in ids){
    // изначальный некорректный пример:
    // requests.push( request(id) );
    // в действительности - так:
    requests.push( request( ids.shift() ) );
}
```

Завершения дожидаюсь так:

```
$.when.apply($, requests)
    .done(() => {
        // показать модальное окно с сообщением
        showMessage('Ok');
    })
    .fail(() => {
        // показать модальное окно с сообщением
        showMessage('Failed');
    });
```

Проблема в том, что запросы выполняются не все, но `.done` срабатывает и выдаётся окно с рапортом об успешном окончании работы. Т.е., если список `ids` содержит, к примеру, 6 элементов, то запросов выполнится 3 (и столько же обещаний находится в `requests`).
Вопрос - почему реальное количество запросов, попадающих в `requests`, не соответствует запланированному (кол-во элементов `ids`) и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Можно попробовать `Promise.all(requests).then(...)`

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что в `ids` 6 элементов в момент работы цикла? 2. Вы понимаете, что `for... in` проходит по индексам, а не по самим элементам?

Comment: @RaulRojas по сути это что-то даст? Я так понимаю, замена jQuery на чистый JS просто будет.

Comment: @Regent в консоли смотрю - шесть. Да, вероятно, дело в этом, моя ошибка - привёл некорректный пример. Там используется `shift` как `requests.push( request( ids.shift() ) );` в цикле for in и в этом, видимо, причина проблемы.

Comment: @Ivan сделайте, например, `for (let id of ids) { requests.push(request(id)); }`

Comment: @Regent проблема не в подстановке `id` (индекс элемента) вместо требуемого `ids[id]` (значение элемента), проблема в использовании `shift` внутри цикла. Т.е. значение подставлялось корректное, возвращённое `shift`, но размер массива менялся, что и приводило к выполнению не всех запросов (не все они попадали в очередь). Я в вопросе и комментарии пометил, что привёл некорректный пример, и изменил его.

Comment: @Ivan я свой вариант привёл не только как исправление `for..in`, но и как исправление ошибки с `shift` (нет `shift` - нет проблем). Вообще, если вам нужно только пройтись по элементам массива, то портить массив при этом (с помощью `shift`, например) нет никакого резона.

Comment: @Ivan, а чем Вас нативные промисы не устраивают?

Comment: @RaulRojas а при чем тут "устраивают"/"не устраивают"? Речь ведь была о том, что это никак не повлияет на решение проблемы автора.

Comment: @Regent переделываю имеющийся скрипт. Ожидал от цикла с `shift` (которая там уже была, при этом изначальный размер массива не сохранялся и в `for` не подставлялся) извлечения всех элементов из массива и потому изначально не было мысли от неё избавляться. Спасибо за помощь. А есть штатная возможность получить в .done результат последнего запроса?  Сейчас приходится внутри ф-и `request` обрабатывать результат каждого запроса, хотелось бы от этого избавиться и использовать только последний (он содержит всю нужную информацию).

Comment: @Regent, возможно, я не так понял вопрос.